# Jquery 3D rings

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d

I want to do a 3D effect which as same as this website http://www.asianimedia.com/

But i need it in jquery , and not in flash.

I have try JQUERY 3D engine, by using this library i can do the similar thing, but i need 99% same, which i cant do it at this moment

can anyone tell me how to do it? or is there any better 3D library

this is the 3D engine that i currently using 
http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/09/3d-plane-for-jquery-3d-engine/

Comment: You could simply use CSS3 transitions, no extra library would be required that way. There should be quite a bit of information around the place about them! :) Only downside is a slight lack of support in IE which you may work around with the 3D engine your using

Comment: By the way, you say you need 99% the same, what isn't the same at the moment with your approach, what do you need to improve or fix?

Comment: becoz client need it in js, instead of flash, and the source of the flash is lost, and the path is hardcode in the flash

Comment: So you haven't got anything at the moment using the library? You haven't made any progress? See my comment on my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so just using jQuery (no css transforms, meaning it should be pretty compatible), I've come up with the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/andyc/ZncP6/

```
var numOfBoxes = 10;
var boxContainer = $(".boxcontainer");
var gap = 360 / (numOfBoxes);

for (var i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++) {
    $("<div>").attr("data-offset", (gap * i)).addClass("box").appendTo(boxContainer);
}

$(".box").each(function() {
    var box = $(this);
    positionBox(box, 0);
});


$({position: 0}).animate({position: 360}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function() {
        var currentPosition = this.position;
        console.log(currentPosition);
        $(".box").each(function() {
            var box = $(this);
            positionBox(box, currentPosition);
        });
    }
});

function positionBox(box, position) {
    var newPosition = position + box.data("offset");
    var newRadianPosition = convertToRadians(newPosition);

    var x = Math.cos(newRadianPosition) * 200 + 200;
    var y = Math.sin(newRadianPosition) * 100 + 200;

    var absolutePosition = newPosition % 360;
    if (absolutePosition > 180) {
        box.css("z-index", "0");
    }
    else {
        box.css("z-index", "");
    }

    // Could scale the size of the item here as well as position
    box.css("top", y + "px").css("left", x + "px");
}

function convertToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * (3.14159265 / 180);
}​
```

It's a bit rough and ready, so obviously you'd want to tailor it to your needs. Effectively, what it does is create a custom jQuery animation which each step, increments and repositions the small divs around the centre div. If they are half way, it's z index is changed, creating the illusion of depth.

If you wanted it to look a bit more realistic, you could always resize the divs based on how close they are to the font.

Does this help?

Let me know if you want a bit more of an explanation! :)
Ta!

Comment: thanks a lot, i understand the logic, but it seem not suitable for me, since the angle of the ring is not the one i want, i need the 99% same path as my reference link

Comment: It could be skewed slightly so the angle is more the same. I'm sure that wouldn't be a hard thing to implement yourself, you just need to change the maths a bit! :) I don't think you're going to get anyone giving you the full solution, this is meant to be a 'help-with-coding' site, not a 'give-me-the-answer-and-source-code' site :)

Comment: i have already did it, the angle is actually same, becoz i decomplie the code in flash and re code it to js, it give the same result

Comment: Cool, glad you got something in the end!